# Beginning with SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would like to dive into the world of SharePoint, but don't really know where to start. Maybe I haven't searched hard or long enough, but browsing through Stack Overflow gave me very little pointers.

So long story short, does any of you have pointers for me where to begin with learning SharePoint, what to do and maybe more important, what NOT to do...

My background: I have experience in Perl and Java, and I'm fairly new to C#, but still in the process of learning this language.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you become at least reasonably fluent with C# before trying something like SharePoint as its not a particularly easy platform to develop for.

Having said that a great place to start is with the channel9 videos take a look here http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/sharepoint?sort=viewed

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My 'noobness' in C# is indeed a thing that crossed my mind, although I found C# so far not to hard to learn, mainly because I see much resemblance with Java.

Answer (score 2):

[Getting Started with SharePoint 2010 Development–Links and Resources](http://msmvps.com/blogs/windsor/archive/2011/08/01/getting-started-with-sharepoint-2010-development-links-and-resources.aspx)